# Reload part of table without full page reload

Tags: javascript, html

I have a simple page:

```html
<table>
  <tr><td>
    include 'top+menu.php';
  </td></tr>
  <tr><td>
    include [new body via post from menu] ie. about.php
  </td></tr>
  <tr><td>
    include 'footer.php';
  </td></tr>
</table>
```

My problem, what I would like is when I click on a menu item is to reload the body without a full page reload/flicker.  Thanks

Google has not been any help - hints, some but not enough to solve my problem

Comment: are you thinking of AJAX? That seems to be the most obvious solution to loading parts of a page and not reloading entire page

Answer (score 0):

If do I understand correctly, you want to replace with AJAX the content returned by the page selected by the link in the menu.

Ignoring that using a table is a bad choice to make the page layout, this is a page output example:

**HTML Page**

```html
<head>
    <script src="main.js"></script>
</head>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="https://website.com/home.php" class="menu-link"></a></li>
                <li><a href="https://website.com/about.php" class="menu-link"></a></li>
            </ul>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <div id="body">
                
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            include 'footer.php';
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**main.js**

```js
const getPage = href => {
    // Attempt to make a fetch request
    fetch(href)
        .then(response => {
            if (!response.ok) {
                throw new Error('Network response was not ok')
            }
            //replace the content of <div id="body">
            document.getElementById('body').innerHTML(response)
        })
        .catch(error => {
            // Handle any errors that occur during the fetch request
            console.error('Fetch request error:', error)
        })
}
document.querySelector('.menu-link').addEventListener('click', e => {
    e.preventDefault()
    const page = e.target.href
    getPage(href)
})
```

Comment: Thanks for the response.  the top/menu and footer still repaint.  And what is wrong with a table?

Comment: I corrected the selector on the main.js file. The AJAX request should not trigger a total repaint of the page, but only the content inside the div with `id="body"`. Can you update your question, adding what you changed?
For the layout, you can use `div`s and CSS. The table should be used as a table, except for the case of HTML emails, where is the safe way to make a layout.

Comment: Think I'm on the way to solving my problem - the reload of the image of our building - big FLASH!  css, body, background-image, size, position, etc then div, position for the rest of the page.  Thanks

Comment: Interesting - I've been working on the live server (ya, bad me).  I downloaded to my in-house server and the reload flash of the image of the building - doesn't.   live is Ubuntu, local is Fedora.  I love computers, I love computers, I love....